# is there a way to change position of command palette when open it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want my command palette displays on the right side of the editor not centre position. Can  I modify settings.json or something else to do that ？ Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could follow [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/17268#issuecomment-448500708). It may be what you're trying to achieve :)

You may have to download [VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) from the repo and [compile it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute) and then install your custom compiled version.